# Elementary Question Regarding 2-adic Valuation

Tags: number-theory

What exactly is the 2-adic evaluation of an integer?  Is it related to modular arithmetic?

For example, how exactly does the definition of the ruler function work?

Comment: Is this what you are referring to or something else? http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0097316508000459/1-s2.0-S0097316508000459-main.pdf?_tid=0abd7352-e378-11e2-a2af-00000aacb360&acdnat=1372811729_126e90d6b8f17aa1201808ba4d3d422f

Comment: Precisely, although perhaps at a simplified level.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Comment: Yes, I was just hoping someone might be able to help explain it more clearly with respect to the ruler function.

Answer (score 2):

The 2-adic valuation of a number is the largest number of times you can divide it by 2 and still get an integer. In other words, it is the exponent of the 2 in the prime factorization of the number.